# Elevate permission to create file in C:\windows with Python 3.x

Tags: python, admin, root, uac, privileges

I have tried every other solution to create a text file in C:\windows but unfortunately after performing the user uac permission and giving administrative access, windows still doesn't allow to create this file, pycharm console output PermossionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\textfile.log'.
Is there a way to create a file in C windows root by entering the admin user and pass in windows uac?
Thank you!

Comment: Wouldn't this be a massive security concerns if arbitrary programs could manipulate UAC popups, and subvert the entire reason for UAC in the first place?

Comment: You need to run the python interpreter as administrator. Try running pycharm as admin. You can also run the file-creating script in a new subprocess as administrator from your main script, if you want to be prompted for your admin password during execution.

Comment: Ok, sure, but how would I do that, to create a new subprocess as admin and be prompted for my admin credentials, and given these credentials to carry on and work thru the text file.

Comment: Why do you need to create a file in the OS install directory?

Comment: Because this way normal user wouldn't be able to delete this file without an admin permission.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

1. Try from out of PyCharm, sometimes that could be a problem.
2. Run the python file itself as administrator.

Comment: I have tried from outside, after converting the py file into exe, and unfortunately  even running the exe as admin it still doesn't pass thru the file manipulation writing data into it.

Comment: Did u try running the python script in an elevated command prompt